# IOServiceGetMatchingServices does not find some devices on some Macs

Tags: macos, io, usb

I have an issue with an app that monitors the USB bus for changes. Specifically if I want to get a list of attached USB sevices, I am using the code below. What is strange is that *some* users (and nautally not my machines) do not see one or two devices.
Those devices DO show up in the IORegistryExplorer, and show registered.

The machines for which this is not working are also running 10.6 and are also MacBook Pros.

> CFMutableDictionaryRef service_properties = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL,NULL);
>       CFMutableDictionaryRef child_props = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL,NULL);

```
kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                  IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBEHCI"), &io_objects);

if(kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
    exit(1);

while((io_service= IOIteratorNext(io_objects)))
{

    kr = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(io_service, &service_properties, kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions);

    io_iterator_t   iter;
    kr = IORegistryEntryGetChildIterator(io_service, kIOServicePlane, &iter);
    io_registry_entry_t     child;
    while( (child = IOIteratorNext( iter )))
    {
        kr = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(child, &child_props,  kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions );
        NSLog(@"%@",child_props);
    }

    IOObjectRelease(io_service);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to poll all the bus types:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){

if(i==0)kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(myMasterPort,
                                      IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBEHCI"), &io_objects);
if(i==1)kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(myMasterPort,
                                      IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBOHCI"), &io_objects);
if(i==2)kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(myMasterPort,
                                      IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBUHCI"), &io_objects);

if(kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
    exit(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're matching on entirely the wrong thing. You're matching against the physical controller used in the Mac (`EHCI`, `UHCI`, `OHCI`). This will fail whenever they invent a new controller standard, such as `XHCI` in new Macs since 2012 (for USB 3 compatibility).

What you probably want to do is to match against `IOUSBDevice`, that what I do when I want to match every device in the system. This is also how its done in the `Deva` sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeremy : there are other possibilities than `AppleUSBEHCI`

Maybe you probably know that (just in case):

```
ioreg -l | grep AppleUSB
```

should show the alive USB status on your machine